# Where to find the .sty file?

Tags: packages

stupid question here where is the .sty file?

e.g. I don't see any .sty file here
http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/breqn/

Comment: Try https://www.ctan.org/pkg/breqn.  The `dtx` file is compiled to produce both the documentation as well as the style file.

Comment: They are in `.dtx` files. Why you not use tools of your LaTeX distribution for installing missed package (at MikTeX is named Console). Simpler and more reliably.

Comment: basically to use with overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/What_packages_do_you_support%3F
actually I'm not sure  how that whole thing works either

Comment: Do you get any error without providing the sty file?